# What's the difference between module, package and library in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, module, package

What's the difference between module, package and library in Haskell?

From http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html
Prelude: a standard **module** imported by default into all Haskell modules.

From http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Base_package
Base package: The base **package** contains the Prelude and its support libraries, and a large collection of useful **libraries** ranging from data structures to parsing combinators and debugging utilities.

Thanks.

See also:
[What's the difference between a Python module and a Python package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948494/whats-the-difference-between-a-python-module-and-a-python-package)

Comment: A *package* is a collection of *modules*, which are explained in the language report, together with data such as versions and descriptions. One often calls a package with modules that are primarily intended for use in other projects a *library*.

Comment: @gspr if *library* is just another name for *package*, what does it mean when ezyang says *Cabal only supports a single public library per package*? [source](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/5j4szk/nyhug_backpack_to_work_towards_backpack_in/dbe2yq3/)

Comment: what about haskell program ?

Answer (score 26):

A **module** is a set of functions, types, classes, ... put together in a common namespace.

A **library** is a set of modules which makes sense to be together and that can be used in a program or another library.

A **package** is a unit of distribution that can contain a library or an executable or both. It's a way to share your code with the community.

Note that a library doesn't have to be in isolation in a package. That is, it's perfectly acceptable to have a library in your project that is used inside this project. The code is therefore seperated from the rest for clarity and maintainability. This is also a good way to isolate some general-purpose from your business logic code and this lib could eventually be extracted and shared between projects or with the community if needed.

Comment: Can a package also contain multiple libraries? Can a package contain different modules both inside and outside libraries? Where do signatures and interface fit in, introduced by Backpack?

Comment: "packages are the things on Hackage" A Latter : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480982/packages-modules-and-import-in-haskell?rq=1