# How do you import Data.Heap?

Tags: haskell

Sorry for such a dumb question. I'm trying to import [Data.Heap](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/heap-1.0.3/docs/Data-Heap.html#t:HeapT), but I get this error message:

```
> import Data.Heap

<no location info>: error:
    Could not find module ‘Data.Heap’
    Perhaps you meant
      Data.Map (from containers-0.5.7.1@containers-0.5.7.1)
```

Haven't had trouble with other imports.

Thanks.

Comment: You have to install `Data.Heap`. There are two packages that have a `Data.Heap` module: [`heap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/heap-1.0.3/docs/Data-Heap.html) and [`heaps`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/heaps-0.3.4.1/docs/Data-Heap.html). If you for instance use `cabal` you can use `cabal install heap[s]` (pick one).

Comment: Thanks. I tried: "C:\Users\facuser>cabal install Data.Heap" and got
"cabal: The file does not exist 'Data.Heap'." Same for "Heaps"

Comment: Try `cabal install heaps`. Package names are case sensitive, although I don't know whether that changes under Windows.

Comment: `Data.Heap` is a *module name*. To install, you need to use the corresponding *package name*. They are different. (E.g., the *package* named `bytestring` contains several *modules* named `Data.ByteString`, `Data.ByteString.Char8`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

As was described in the comments, you need to install the package which contains the module `Data.Heap`. (See [this related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16997950/whats-the-difference-between-module-package-and-library-in-haskell) question on the difference between packages and modules in Haskell)

On the [Hackage page](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/heap-1.0.3/docs/Data-Heap.html), in the upper left-hand corner you will see the name and version of the package you are looking at:
[image: heap package name: heap-1.0.3]
If you are using stack, then add `heap` to your `build-depends` section of `project.cabal` file, and rebuild. If you are just using cabal, simply run `cabal install heap` to get the most recent version of the package installed on your system.

Comment: When I tried > cabal install heap I got a popup saying please insert a disk into drive D. None of the three buttons (Ignore, Continue, or Try Again) worked. I had to kill GHCi from the task manager to get rid of the popup and to close the command prompt window. This happened whether or not GHCi was running when I tried to run the command.  Now I can't start GHCi without getting that popup, which blocks everything.

Comment: You don't run the install from GHCi, you run it in your project directory, then start GHCi. If you're new, I'd recommend just using stack as it simplifies this whole process.

Comment: I didn't try to run install from GHCi. I ran it from a command prompt window. I am new with respect to this sort of sys-admin-level stuff for Haskell. Telling me to run stack doesn't help since I've never run stack. I've always just downloaded the Haskell platform and installed it according to the directions. Never needed to do anything else.

Comment: This is getting to be a bit much. Even after restarting the computer I can no longer start GHCi without the popup requiring a disk in drive D: Can't get rid of the popup, and the popup blocks GHCi. This is terrible. I'm in worse shape than when I started.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45385105/cant-start-haskell for a solution to the drive D issue.