# "Insert disk into Drive D" blocks Haskell from starting

Tags: haskell

This question is an outgrowth of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45362161/how-do-you-import-data-heap). In that question I asked for advice for importing Data.Heap. I was told that I first had to install Heap. As instructed I ran

```
> cabal install Heap
```

A Windows error box popped up telling me that there was no disk in Drive D and that I had to insert one. None of the three buttons (Ignore, Continue, or Try Again) worked. I had to kill GHCi from the task manager to get rid of the popup and to close the command prompt window. This happened whether or not GHCi was running when I tried to run the command. Now I can't start GHCi without getting that popup, which blocks everything.

I tried turning the computer off and then on again later. Same popup. I even uninstalled the Haskell platform and reinstalled it. (It is version 8.0.2-a.) Still the same popup when I start GHCi. (I use the platform-installed shortcut WinGHCi to start GHCi.)

I would appreciate advice for avoiding that popup. Otherwise I can't run GHCi at all.

Thanks.

Comment: That’s pretty strange. Was there any output from `cabal install Heap`? Did you actually kill GHCi, or something else with a similar name (I don’t think `cabal install` runs GHCi)?

Comment: I've heard of this bug before.  It has something to do with the msys install ghc is using being messed up somehow, but I don't know how to fix it. I know it's more complicated than just reinstalling ghc.

Comment: Maybe you should use Haskell Stack? https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's a long-standing problem. (See [here](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&rlz=1C1GTPM_enUS696US702&q=%22insert+disk+into+drive+d%22&oq=%22insert+disk+into+drive+d%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30k1l4.9554.10512.0.12304.2.2.0.0.0.0.93.180.2.2.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.179...0i7i30k1.8khjrUPt__0) and [here](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&rlz=1C1GTPM_enUS696US702&q=please+insert+disk+into+drive+d&oq=please+insert+disk+into+drive+d&gs_l=psy-ab.12..0i20k1l2j0l2.5949.8667.0.12432.2.2.0.0.0.0.89.176.2.2.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.174...0i7i30k1j0i30k1.B31B5fzEbBc)). It may have to do with gcc, and it may have to do with Microsoft.

One solution is to go to Settings. (I'm on Windows 10.) Search for Disk Management. At the bottom scroll down to Disk D. Right click and select Change Drive Letter. Change it to something else(!).

That seems to do the trick. Given how long this problem seems to have been around, I don't understand why it hasn't been fixed.

I am now able to use Command Prompt to

```
>cabal install Heap
```

and then in GHCi (REPL)

```
Prelude> import Heap
```

That was the original problem.

Comment: That would help. Where/how do you file a feature request?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the down-vote. I'm disappointed that it seems unacceptable to express frustration. My rant was labelled as such. In addition it was expressed politely and without name-calling. I don't think it can be categorized as trolling or disruption.

Comment: Removed the rant.