# Importing sub-packages with stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I don't understand how to import "sub-packages" in stack (if this is not the correct term, please let me know so I can edit).

Here's the top of a simple file:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Conduit where

import Data.Conduit
import qualified Data.Conduit.List as CL
import qualified Data.Conduit.Binary as CB
```

Two dependencies are listed.  In myproject.cabal, I have:

```
executable myproject
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  main-is:             Main.hs
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5,
                       conduit
```

`stack build -v` gives me this error:

```
2018-02-08 13:28:06.923836: [warn] 7 | import qualified Data.Conduit.Binary as CB
```

I am not sure what to include in the cabal executable directive, each of these throws errors:

```
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5,
                       conduit,
                       conduit.list,
                       conduit.binary

  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5,
                       conduit,
                       conduit-list
                       conduit-binary
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Data.Conduit.Binary`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-10.4/conduit-extra-1.2.3.2/Data-Conduit-Binary.html) is a *module*. It is part of a *package* called [`conduit-extra`](https://www.stackage.org/lts-10.4/package/conduit-extra-1.2.3.2). Packages are what Stack (and cabal-install, were you using that instead) installs, and what you should add to the `build-depends` of the .cabal file:

```
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5,
                       conduit,
                       conduit-extra
```

As for [`Data.Conduit.List`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-10.4/conduit-1.2.13/Data-Conduit-List.html), it is part of the `conduit` package, so you don't need another entry for it. One quick way of clarifying such things is [doing a Hoogle search for the module](https://www.stackage.org/lts-10.4/hoogle?q=Data.Conduit.List) (the package it belongs to will be pointed out in the top bar of the documentation page).

See also: [*What's the difference between module, package and library in Haskell?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16997950/2751851); [*Packages, modules and import in Haskell*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5480982/2751851).